# Put single quote in each values inside a string in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to put a single quote in each values in a string that is separated by comma to include it in an SQL query (ex. `"AND STAT IN ('11', '12')`. Please help me if you have any ideas.

Sample data: `string sStatus = "10,20,30,40";`

I have already tried splitting each of the values.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sStatus))
        {
            string[] sStatList = sStatus.Split(',');

            foreach (string p in sStatList)
            {
            }

            sFilter = String.Format(" AND STAT IN ({0})", sStatList);
        }
```

Comment: Please don't build up SQL queries like this, it makes you vulnerable to injection attacks. If you are using SQL Server, look into using table-valued parameters to achieve this sort of functionality.

Comment: string sStatus = "10,20,30,40";
var quoted = "'" + sStatus.Replace(",","','") + "'";
Console.WriteLine(quoted);

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Select()`.

```cs
string[] sStatList = sStatus.Split(',');

var res = string.Join(",", sStatList.Select(s => $"'{s}'"));
```

This requires `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: do I need to add any libraries related to that? I'm currently having an error

Comment: @VinaChan: Please learn to think like a programmer and don't say things like *I'm having an error.* You are only able to work the error if you say what that error actually is. VERY IMPORTANT! Are you missing a `using` statement? We don't know.

Comment: @VinaChan you must include System.Linq to make the error go away.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        string[] sStatList = sStatus.Split(',');
        string sFilter= "";
            foreach (string p in sStatList)
            {
                sFilter = sFilter+ ("'" + p + "',");
            }
        if(sFilter.EndsWith(","))
        {
            sFilter = sFilter.Substring(0,sFilter.Length-1);
        }
        sFilter = " AND STAT IN (" + sFilter + ")";
```

Comment: I already tried this but it will put a comma on the last value. Ex. '10', '20',

Comment: the next statement (if) after `foreach`, remove the last comma.

Answer (score 0):

@oika's answer is on the right track but it's not quite right for what you're trying to do. However `Select` is the answer here... like this though:

You'll need to add a reference to `Linq`:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then

```
var sStatuses = sStatus.Split(',');

var parsedsStatuses = string.Join(",", sStatuses.Select(x => $"'{x}'"));
var sql = $"AND STAT IN ({ parsedsStatuses })";
```

Of course you do want to be careful doing this, as it opens up a vulnerability for `SQL Injection`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `string.Join` like this:

```
var status = "10,20,30,40";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
{
    var sStatList = status.Split(',');

    filter = $"'{string.Join("','", sStatList)}'";
}
```

Another option you have, would be to use the `string.Replace`:

```
var status = "10,20,30,40";
filter = $"'{status.Replace(",","','")}'";
```

Either way, you need to validate the input to avoid [SQL Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-2017). Consider following:

```
status = "10,20,30');/*,*/ DROP TABLE Users;//";
```

[Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) for example supports this directly:}

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id IN @ids"
var results = connection.Query(sql, status.Split(','));
```

and there are alternative orms that will handle parameterisation.

As a side note: avoid using the Hungarian notation in C# as [microsoft also recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions). The Hungarian notation where you specify the variable type using a prefix is useless information and adds noise, especially VS and VS Code will tell you the type anyway.